# Insertions, deletions and substitutions between two strings

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance

Given string A,B I need to compute the number of insertions, deletions and substitutions for B to become A. What would be a good algorithm for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's known as [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).